# How do I make the header non-transparent when I scroll up a bit - not only at the absolute top of the page?

Tags: css, elementor

I am currently using Elementor Pro in Wordpress and is trying to make the sticky header reactive when scrolling. With the piece of code below, I have managed to make the header smaller and a bit transparent when I scroll down. However, to get the header to be non-transparent again, I need to scroll all the way to the top of the page again. What I would like to have happen is that the header becomes non-transparent after scrolling up no matter where on the page I am. Is this possible?

```
selector.elementor-sticky--effects{
   background-color: #1c4d5d !important
}

selector{
   transition: background-color 1s ease !important;
}

selector.elementor-sticky--effects >.elementor-container{
   min-height: 80px;
}

selector > .elementor-container{
   transition: min-height 0.5s ease !important;
}
```

And please excuse my, potentially, super obvious problem to fix - I am new to this whole world :-)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Follow this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp